# Como acessar a câmera do celular via Web Site?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tem como acessar a câmera do celular em um sistema web(`Não é app`) utilizando javascript?

- Qual a solução para isso?

Comment: Configura minha resposta Igor, eu testei e funcionou!

Comment: Ok. Irei testar, obrigado Marconi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui nessa resposta [How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app)

No iPhone iOS6 e do Android ICS em diante, o HTML5 tem a seguinte tag, que permite que você tire fotos do seu dispositivo:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

`capture` pode ter valores como câmera, filmadora e áudio.

Comment: Então, eu gostaria de acessar o recurso(Câmera) direto, sem ter que selecionar a imagem.

Answer (score 1):

O html5 permite isso utilizando o tag

```
capture="camera"
```

Comment: Qual tag? Não está clara sua resposta